# Can't get rid of indentation (even with \noindent)

Tags: indentation

I'd like to have the indentation in front of `\begin{tabular}{l}
\textsc{code}\\
11-22-33-44
\end{tabular}%` removed:

[image]

If it's a really easy problem, I must admit I'm not seeing it at the moment.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[
fontsize=12pt,
a4paper,
DIV=15,
parskip=half
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{
lmodern
}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
%\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{flushleft}
Words\\
More Words
\end{flushleft}%
%\noindent%
%\begin{flushleft}
%\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth} %
%\begin{flushleft}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{l}
\textsc{code}\\
11-22-33-44
\end{tabular}%
%\end{flushleft}
%\end{minipage} %
\hfill
%\begin{minipage}[t]{6cm}
%\begin{flushright}%
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\textsc{place,} & \textsc{date}\\
Place, & \today
\end{tabular} %
%\end{flushright}
%\end{minipage}
%\end{flushleft}
\begin{flushleft}
\bfseries Words
\end{flushleft}
\begin{flushleft}
Something,
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\begin{tabular}{@{}l}` to suppress the space before the column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
```

`@{}` removes the `\tabcolsep`.

It has nothing to do with the indentation of paragraphs. You have `parskip=half`, the reason why `\noindent` is superfluous.